# MDX: How to remove the MEASURES dimension from TUPLE returned by ROOT(), in a calculated member

Tags: scope, mdx, multidimensional-array

I want to get a weight or ratio of portion to total within the scope of all the dimensions so I tried this:

```
SCOPE([MEASURES].[Weight]);
    THIS = [MEASURES].[Some Value] / ([MEASURES].[Some Value], ROOT());
    FORMAT_STRING(THIS) = "#,##0.00";    
END SCOPE;
```

But this returns

**#Error MdxScript(Performance) (3713, 16) The 'Measures' hierarchy appears more than once in the tuple.**

Obviously since the [ROOT()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146076.aspx) returns all the dimensions, including the MEASURES one. How would I remove it from the above statement please?

I'm pretty sure that I should be using the [EXTRACT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145980.aspx) function, but I don't see what the syntax would be.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a trick:

```
THIS = [MEASURES].[Some Value] / SUM(ROOT(), [MEASURES].[Some Value]);
```